# JMSSecuritybundle throwing "security.expressions.expression" defined for definition "security.expressions.expression

Tags: symfony

i recently configured JMSSecurityExtraBundle and when i try to add an expression to my firewall rules it throws me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException'
>   with message 'The parent definition "security.expressions.expression"
>   defined for definition
>   "security.expressions.expression.3b9a3b9db79b52922a36b870bc46e5b114425575"
>   does not exist.'

I followed the exact description as described on this page:

> http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/installation

This is when the error occurs:

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/foo, access: "hasRole('FOO') and hasRole('BAR')" }
```

Comment: hmh, really can't find a solution to this

Answer (score 2):

You have to activate the expressions for it to work.
add

```
jms_security_extra:
    expressions: true
```

to your config.yml and try it out